# Scan files sequentially in batch file by name

Tags: html, batch-file, for-loop, solr

I'd need to scan files sequentially by name, as my script seems not to use this criteria.
I should process some html in a folder, before 1.html, then 2.html, then 3.html and then upload the files in solr setting the id equal to the name (so 1.html should have id=1 etc.).

This is my bat script but it seems not to have the exact behaviour I want.

```
 @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set /a "i = 1"

for %%f in (*.html) do (
    set "N=%%f"
    curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=!i!&commit=true" -F "myfile=@!N!"
    set /a "i = i + 1"
    )

)
endlocal
```

So the page is uploaded correctly in solr, but the id doesn't match the page uploaded.
For example page 9.html talks about a football player, but in solr the page 9.html with id=9 talks about another thing.

I think the error is the i counter, I'd not need it and literal.id should be set on the value of the name of the page without extension, so page 1.html should have id=1 but i don't know ho to get only this part of the name file.

Thanks for help

Comment: `%%~nf` should return the name (without extension) of the file referenced in `%%f`. See `for /?` for a complete reference.

Answer (score 0):

`%%~nf` should return the name (without extension) of the file referenced in `%%f`. See `for /?` for a complete reference.